# Vertical layout poorly formats after dynamically adding widget

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm having a problem with a `QVBoxLayout` that I'm hoping someone has insight on. I'm currently building a GUI for electrical tests. I have a main `QTabWidget` which contains two tabs - one for Electrodes and one for Tests. Each of these tabs contains *another* `QTabWidget` object, where one can dynamically add and modify **electrode tabs** in the first case and **test tabs** in the second. Each test tab defines an electrical test which each depends on all electrodes.

Thus, tach tab of the Test sub-`QTabWidget` has a scroll area containing *n* widgets of the custom type called `ElectrodeFrame` (super type = `QFrame`), one for each electrode where *n* is the number of electrodes. An example of a Test sub-`QTabWidget` Tab can be seen here:

[image: Good Layout]

**I'm working on inserting a new `ElectrodeFrame` to the scroll area in each Test subtab when a new Electrode Tab is added**. The `ElectrodeFrame` is inserting properly, but the problem is that the `QVboxLayout` in which they sit does not update its size to accommodate the new `ElectrodeFrame`. I have attached two pictures:

- In the first, seen below, (Test 1) the Test subtab was created ("Test 1"), and *then* one additional Electrode subtab (in addition to the default one) was added. We can see that they all compressed and overlap in the `QScrollArea`
- In the second, seen above, (Test 2) the Test subtab ("Test 2") was created *after* the additional Electrode subab were created, and we can see that the `ElectrodeFrame`s are *not* compressed in this case.

[image]

Does anyone have insight as to what the issue is here? I have tried calling `update()` on the widget whose layout is the `QVboxLayout` in which the `ElectrodeFrame`s sit

Additional information that may be helpful:

- I have vertical spacer at the bottom of the `QScrollArea` (denoted in red in the first image)
- I have used `setWidgetResiable(False)` on the scroll area because it was squeezing the `ElectrodeFrame`s (and violating their minimum size bounds defined in the class, which I did not understand)
- The size in which all of the `ElectrodeFrame`s are compressed does not change regardless of how many new ones are added

Minimum Reproducible Example here:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class topLevelWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.resize(720, 500)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralWidgetLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)

        # Create main tab widget
        self.mainTabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mainTabs, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        # Add a tab to mainTabs for Electrodes
        self.electrodesTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.electrodeLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.electrodesTab)
        self.mainTabs.addTab(self.electrodesTab, "Electrodes")
        # Add another tab widget under this tab
        self.electrodesSubTabs = TabWidget(self.electrodesTab)
        self.electrodesSubTabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.electrodeLayout.addWidget(self.electrodesSubTabs, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        # Repeat for "Tests" tab
        self.testsTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.testsLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.testsTab)
        self.mainTabs.addTab(self.testsTab, "Tests")
        self.testsSubTabs = TabWidget(self.testsTab)
        self.testsSubTabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.testsLayout.addWidget(self.testsSubTabs, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        # Now put in proper widget into the subtabs
        self.test1TestsTab = []
        self.add_clicked_Test()

        self.electrode1Tab = []
        self.add_clicked_electrodes(first=True)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainTabs)


        ### CONNECTIVITY ###
        # '+' buttons make new subtabs
        self.electrodesSubTabs.plusClicked.connect(self.add_clicked_electrodes)
        self.testsSubTabs.plusClicked.connect(self.add_clicked_Test)

        # Deleting tabs
        self.electrodesSubTabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.delete_clicked_electrodes)
        self.testsSubTabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.delete_clicked_Test)


    def add_clicked_electrodes(self, first=False):
        index = self.electrodesSubTabs.count()
        self.electrode1Tab.append(electrodeInstanceTab(self.electrodesSubTabs))
        self.electrodesSubTabs.addTab(self.electrode1Tab[index], "Electrode " + str(index + 1))

        if not first:
            for testTab in self.test1TestsTab:
                frame = electrodeFrame()
                testTab.electrodeFrameList.insert(index, frame)
                testTab.vbox.addWidget(frame)
        else:
            pass


    def add_clicked_Test(self):
        index = self.testsSubTabs.count()
        self.test1TestsTab.append(testInstanceTab(self.testsSubTabs))
        self.testsSubTabs.addTab(self.test1TestsTab[index], "Test " + str(index + 1))


    def delete_clicked_electrodes(self, index):
        currentQWidget = self.electrodesSubTabs.widget(index)
        currentQWidget.deleteLater()
        self.electrodesSubTabs.removeTab(index)

        # Rename the remaining tabs
        self.electrode1Tab.pop(index)
        for i in range(len(self.electrode1Tab)):
            self.electrodesSubTabs.setTabText(i, "Electrode " + str(i + 1))

        # If deleting the only remaining tab, fill in a new one
        if index == 0 and self.electrodesSubTabs.count() == 0:
            self.add_clicked_electrodes()

    def delete_clicked_Test(self, index):
        currentQWidget = self.testsSubTabs.widget(index)
        currentQWidget.deleteLater()
        self.testsSubTabs.removeTab(index)

        # Rename the remaining tabs
        self.test1TestsTab.pop(index)
        for i in range(len(self.test1TestsTab)):
            self.testsSubTabs.setTabText(i, "Test " + str(i + 1))

        # If deleting the only remaining tab, fill in a new one
        if index == 0 and self.testsSubTabs.count() == 0:
            self.add_clicked_Test()


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    plusClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    deleteClicked = True

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.tabBar().installEventFilter(self)

        self.add_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self, text="+")
        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.plusClicked)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.tabBar() and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize:
            r = self.tabBar().geometry()
            h = r.height()
            self.add_button.setFixedSize((h - 1) * QtCore.QSize(1, 1))
            self.add_button.move(r.right(), 0)
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class electrodeInstanceTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, name=None):
        super(electrodeInstanceTab, self).__init__()
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.electrodeNameVal = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.electrodeNameVal)


class electrodeFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    # Objects of this type populate the scrollbox in the Tests tab subtabs
    def __init__(self):
        super(electrodeFrame, self).__init__()

        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.setMinimumHeight(250)
        self.setMaximumHeight(300)

        # Main vertical layout (in which the following horizontal layouts sit)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # 1st Horizontal Layout
        self.horizontalLayout_1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label1Text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.line1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
        self.horizontalLayout_1.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.horizontalLayout_1.addWidget(self.label1Text)
        self.horizontalLayout_1.addWidget(self.line1)
        self.horizontalLayout_1.addWidget(self.checkbox)
        # Add spacer to keep everything pushed left, then add horz layout to main vert layout
        newSpacer = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_1.addItem(newSpacer)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_1)

        # 2nd Horizontal Layout
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label2Input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label3Input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.label4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label4Input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        newSpacer = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label2Input)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label3)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label3Input)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label4)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label4Input)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(newSpacer)

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)

        # 3rd Horizontal Layout
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.label5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label5Input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.label6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label6Input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.label7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label7Input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.label8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combobox.addItem("")
        self.combobox.addItem("")
        newSpacer = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label5)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label5Input)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label6)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label6Input)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label7)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label7Input)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label8)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.combobox)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(newSpacer)

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)

        # Bottom line for separation
        self.bottomLine = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.bottomLine.setMinimumHeight(20)
        self.bottomLine.setMaximumHeight(20)
        self.bottomLine.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.bottomLine.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.bottomLine.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.bottomLine)

        # Change text
        self.label1.setText("Label 1")
        self.label1Text.setText("TEXT")
        self.checkbox.setText("Checkbox")

        self.label2.setText("Label 2")
        self.label3.setText("Label 3")
        self.label4.setText("Label 4")

        self.label5.setText("Label 5")  
        self.label6.setText("Label 6")
        self.label7.setText("Label 7")
        self.label8.setText("Label 8")
        self.combobox.setItemText(0, "Item 1")
        self.combobox.setItemText(1, "Item 2")


class testInstanceTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(testInstanceTab, self).__init__()

        # Create tab and set layout
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Scroll widget for this Test tab
        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.scroll.setLayout(self.scrollLayout)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.electrodeFrameList = []
        # If not application startup, add one test electrodeFrame for each electrode
        try:
            print(len(MainWindow.electrode1Tab))
            for electrode in MainWindow.electrode1Tab:
                frame = electrodeFrame()
                self.electrodeFrameList.append(frame)
                self.vbox.addWidget(frame)
        # If application startup, add 1 tab (because MainWindow DNE yet)
        except:
            frame = electrodeFrame()
            self.electrodeFrameList.append(frame)
            self.vbox.addWidget(frame)

        # Spacer at bottom of scroll widget to keep electrodeFrames compressed
        scrollSpacer = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.vbox.addItem(scrollSpacer)

        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.widget.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        # Scroll Area Properties
        # self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        # Add scroll widget to main Test tab layout
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scroll)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    MainWindow = topLevelWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you correctly, but if I uncomment the `setWidgetResizable` line (which is required for contents that are able to resize themselves), everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was getting some unexpected formatting issues when I had that uncommented, but if that's what needs to change I guess I'll include it and just try to work out the formatting issues. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @musicamante, the problem is that when I set resizable to True, the frames inside the scrollarea violate the minimum size I set for them. Do you know why this is?

Comment: What do you mean by "violate"? It doesn't seem so, can you provide a screenshot of the issue? (besides that, I just noticed that you added a button to the tab widget using the event filter to set its geometry, why are you not using [`setCornerWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setCornerWidget) instead?)

Comment: @musicamante I deleted a bunch of stuff from my original file to get the minimum reproducible example, and it looks like, in the process, I eliminated the problem. Searching for what the issue is now, will post solution if/when I find it

Comment: That's why creating a MRE *before* posting is almost always a good idea: you often end up by solving problems on your own :-)